# Inserting columns with Postgresql by ID

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm working with this movie database and I need to insert the column "director_id" in the movie table. This is what I'm dealing with:

[image]

Above is the `directors` table.

Below is the `movie` table. As you can see, I have a director_id and a movie ID.

[image]

This is where I need to insert the director_id to. But I need to match each director to its corresponding movie (using the id). It should be very simple, but since I'm new to databases, I can't do it. I searched everywhere but I couldn't solve it. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you want an `insert` query, or a `select`?

Comment: I need to insert the column director_id in the other table

Comment: let me edit and specify that better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `JOIN`.

For example:

```
select
  m.id,
  m.title,
  d.director_id
from movie m
join directors d on d.movie_id = m.id
```

**EDIT: Adding redundancy column "director_id"**

If you want to add the column `director_id` permanently you'll need to add the column first (empty), and then update its value. For example:

```
alter table movie add column director_id int;
```

And then:

```
update movie m
set director_id = d.director_id
from directors d
where d.movie_id = m.id
```

Mind that the `UPDATE` statement is run at this moment, and won't keep updating the data in the future, unless you run it again. Therefore, the column `director_id` may become stale, having information from the time when the UPDATE was run.